# Using XPath wildcards to access an object using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am having difficulties to access an object with text ***Current Fund Value***.

Using Firebug on Chrome the element's xpath is :

```
//*[@id="poc"]/div[1]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[1]/th/a
```

Using Firebug on Firefox the element's xpath is :

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[9]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[1]/th/a
```

I tried hard but ( I guess not hard enough ) using below code to access the object which dynamically changes the "div[1]/div[4]" part. Any help will be greatly appreciated:

```
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//a[starts-with(@id, 'poc')] and
contains[(@text, 'Current Fund Value')]")
```

**or**

```
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//input[starts-with(@id, 'poc')] and
contains[(@linktext, 'Current Fund Value')]")
```

**or**

```
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//input[contains[(@text, 'Current
Fund Value')]")
```

**Here is the HTML**

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th>
            <a class="tooltip abbr">
            Current Fund Value:
            </a>
         </th>
         <td class="value dollar"><span class="symbol">$</span><span class="amount">    32,498</span><span class="decimal"><span class="point">.</span><span class="amount">90</span></span></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**Update:**

The way multiple items with same text appear are in different table as  below:

**1st table**

```
//*[@id="poc"]/div[1]/div[3]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/th/a
```

**2nd table**

```
//*[@id="poc"]/div[1]/div[3]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/th/a
```

**3nd table**

```
//*[@id="poc"]/div[1]/div[3]/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/th/a
```

Comment: Add HTML of element you want to find

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the text based search

```
//table//a[contains(text(),'Current Fund Value:')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the problem with relying on just text is that, there are multiple objects with same "Current Fund Value:" on the page.

Comment: But is that the only one in that table? If so, see the edit

Comment: You need to provide the parent of the table and please specify the table you want the text from

Answer (score 0):

So you have a element with id as poc, in which you have multiple table and in one of the table there is a element with text as "Current Fund Value", if this is correct, then you have to mention the table holding this text after you hit the poc element.